# How to read html files on Vapor with Leaf when not using the tau version?

Tags: swift, vapor, leaf

There was a version of Leaf that I was using to load .html files instead of .leaf ones from my Vapor project, which would make syntax coloring for those same files done automatically.

The version of Leaf was `4.0.0-tau.1` and the one for LeafKit was `1.0.0-tau.1.1`

When using this particular version, I could setup leaf in the `configure.swift` file this way:

```
/// Change the classic .leaf extension to .html for the syntax
/// coloring option of Xcode to work each time the app is being load up.
fileprivate func leaf(_ app: Application) {
  if !app.environment.isRelease {
    LeafRenderer.Option.caching = .bypass  // Another issue from the update
  }
  let detected = LeafEngine.rootDirectory ?? app.directory.viewsDirectory
  LeafEngine.rootDirectory = detected
  LeafEngine.sources = .singleSource(
    NIOLeafFiles(fileio: app.fileio,
                 limits: .default,
                 sandboxDirectory: detected,
                 viewDirectory: detected,
                 defaultExtension: "html"))
  app.views.use(.leaf)
}
```

In this code, the `LeafRenderer.Option.caching = .bypass` and the code used with `LeafEngine` do not work anymore since having updated Leaf to `4.1.3` and LeafKit to `1.3.1`.

How can I successfully make this code work as before with the updated Leaf and LeafKit frameworks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this Xcode plugin:
https://github.com/OmranK/VaporLeafPlugIn

It adds Vapor Leaf language support to Xcode IDE. Provides syntax highlighting for Leaf tags as well as HTML tags with auto-indentation all together.

At the moment the plugin supports Xcode up to 13.2 beta. Future Xcode versions will require small update (add new DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID) but it can be easily handled even on already installed plugin.

Comment: The syntax coloring feature is not functioning in Xcode 15. I have also included the DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID for Xcode 15, but the issue persists.

Comment: Not sure whether the plugin is still maintained at all. Personally I don’t use it anymore. Simply because it’s not worth the effort. Nowadays I typically edit Leaf templates in VS Code or similar editor.

Comment: I understand your perspective on the plugin's maintenance status. However, for the sake of maintaining a unified development environment, I prefer using Xcode, and having Leaf syntax highlighting directly within Xcode would be beneficial for my workflow. I appreciate your suggestion about other editors and will explore alternatives if needed. Thank you for sharing your experience!

Comment: DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID must exactly match the version of XCode you use. If you are e.g. on 15.0.1 then DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID should be `EB1EF21B-E756-4D3D-A6EA-E9C57D8C1924`. The easiest way to find out is to check file `Info.plist` located in `Applications/Xcode.app/Contents`.
As for VS Code, there are two plugins making VS code quite solid IDE for swift with all the bells and whistles. Swift support (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sswg.swift-lang) and Leaf syntax (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Francisco.html-leaf)

Comment: When I add the DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID to the Info.plist file, Xcode fails to launch, displaying an alert box indicating that Xcode has quit unexpectedly.
https://ibb.co/N7t2fdy

Comment: In such case, I'm afraid you are on your own. Maybe try to ask the plugin author, whether he plans to support current/future versions of Xcode.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I'll reach out to the plugin author to inquire about their plans for supporting the current version of Xcode